Do we need to install Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2022 in the client side?
I have upgraded a VB.Net windows application from framework 1.1 to 4.7. This application uses Crystal Report. When created the set up of the application and install it in the client machine it threw the below error.
    System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 
    'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception. ---> 
    System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
    'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. 
    The system cannot find the file specified.
    at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..cctor()

Do we need to install CrystalDecision dlls in the client machine ???
Or Is there any way around like we can install our .net application in the client machine without installing crystal reports ??
I installed the Crystal Report for visual studio 2022 file - CR13SP32MSI64_0-80007712 and when upgrading the .net project.The installed application is working in my development machine. But when installed into a machine where there is no crystal report, it threw the above mentioned error.
But after installing the crystal report for visual studio 2022 in the client machine, it worked.
How I can deploy the dot net project with out installing the crystal report in there ??

you really don't, that is one crux with CR, but as the drivers can be deployed with the project legaly and used in a pre build event
